# Sum of 4 integers in 4 arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given four lists A, B, C, D of integer values, compute how many tuples (i, j, k, l) there are such that A[i] + B[j] + C[k] + D[l] is zero.

To make problem a bit easier, all A, B, C, D have same length of N where 0 ≤ N ≤ 500. All integers are in the range of -228 to 228 - 1 and the result is guaranteed to be at most 231 - 1.

Example:

```
Input:
A = [ 1, 2]
B = [-2,-1]
C = [-1, 2]
D = [ 0, 2]
```

Output:
2

Explanation:
The two tuples are:

```
1. (0, 0, 0, 1) -> A[0] + B[0] + C[0] + D[1] = 1 + (-2) + (-1) + 2 = 0
2. (1, 1, 0, 0) -> A[1] + B[1] + C[0] + D[0] = 2 + (-1) + (-1) + 0 = 0
```

I just came up with a solution that concatenates all the vectors and find the 4 sum. But I know there is a better solution. Would someone explain a better solution ? I just see codes using O(N^2) but I can't understand it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for a review of its code. This is better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do not see anything better than `O(N^2)`, here. That's probably the reason why you only "see codes" with this complexity.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would you please as answer, write the algorithm, I can't understand it.

Comment: No, this is your homework, not mine. **You** need to "write the algorithm", not me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doe snot meet the requirements of homework related or similarly posed questions.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious This is not a home work. This is a problem in leetcode. This is NOT a homework. https://leetcode.com/contest/smarking-algorithm-contest-4/problems/4sum-ii/  It was in a contenst

Comment: @SamVarshavchik please see the problem here https://leetcode.com/contest/smarking-algorithm-contest-4/problems/4sum-ii/  it's not a homework, it's a problem in a contenst. and I want to know how to solve it in O(N^2)

Comment: Ok then, it is your problem to solve in the contest, then. Not anyone else's. This is not the web site where one can find someone to tell them the answer to an online contest.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The contest is already finished. The problem is there and I want to know the optimized solution. It's already over.

Comment: Using `base<sup>exp</sup>`, you can denote exponentiation as in -2<sup>28</sup> to 2<sup>28</sup>-1 and [… <] 2<sup>31</sup>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my `O(n^2)` solution:

```
int fourSumCount(vector<int>& A, vector<int>& B, vector<int>& C, vector<int>& D) {
    int n = A.size();
    int result = 0;
    unordered_map<int,int> sumMap1;
    unordered_map<int,int> sumMap2;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            int sum1 = A[i] + B[j];
            int sum2 = C[i] + D[j];
            sumMap1[sum1]++;
            sumMap2[sum2]++;
        }
    }
    for(auto num1 : sumMap1) {
        int number = num1.first;
        if(sumMap2.find(-1 * number) != sumMap2.end()) {
            result += num1.second * sumMap2[-1 * number];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The core observation is - if `W + X + Y + Z = 0` then `W + X = -(Y + Z)`.

Here I used two hash-tables for each of possible sums in both (A, B) and (C, D) find number of occurrences of this sum.

Then, for each `sum(A, B)` we can find if `sum(C, D)` contains complimentary sum which will ensure `sum(A, B) + sum(C, D) = 0`. Add (the number of occurrences of `sum(a, b)`) * (number of occurrences of complimentary `sum(c,d)`) to the result.

Creating `sum(A, B)` and `sum(C, D)` will take `O(n^2)` time. And counting the number of tuples is `O(n^2)` as there are `n^2` sum for each pairs(`A-B`, `C-D`). Other operation like insertion and search on hashtable is amortized `O(1)`. So, the overall time complexity is `O(n^2)`.